# numpy rate with pmt as array

Tags: python, numpy

I am having an issue with calculating the rate with the numpy.rate function. I want to calculate the rate of interest per period for a non-uniform pmt done over nper periods of time that have a certain future value. I am not able to get the input parameters for the function right.

After stripping down the code here is the sample code that I tried.

```
import numpy as np

first_payment = 5100
final_payment = 5400
periods  = 20 
nper = np.arange(start=periods, stop=0, step=-1, dtype=float)
pmt = np.linspace(first_payment, final_payment, 20, dtype=float)
pv = 0
fv = -120000

print(np.rate(nper, pmt, pv, fv))
```

I am expecting an array of returns, I am not sure if this the right approach for a problem like this.

Another approach I tried is that I assumed a rate of return r and tried to solve the equation by multiplying each payment with the number of periods. But that does not look good. TIA.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out in the end?